# php - place multiple items in multiple arrays into one single object

Tags: php, arrays

I have an object called $dbNew that contains multiple arrays with multiple items in each array. Is it possible to put each of these items into one new object so I can run it in a mysql statement that's in a loop. Right now I get a array to string conversion error.

PHP

```
print "<pre>";
print_r($dbNew);
print "</pre>";
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => FMServer_Sample
)
Array
(
    [0] => GolfAudit4
    [1] => iCDS
    [2] => rawhide
)
Array
(
    [0] => Assets
    [1] => PassTracker
    [2] => Scanner
)
Array
(
    [0] => prima
)
Array
(
    [0] => CNAC_db
)
```

PHP

```
$closing = "SELECT log_time FROM log_table WHERE database_name = '$dbNew'";
```

Output

```
Array to string conversion error.
```

Desired Output

```
FMServer_Sample
GolfAudit4
iCDS
rawhide
Assets
PassTracker
Scanner
prima
CNAC_db
```

Comment: What string output are you hoping for? Give us more than a query you want to run, give us how you are trying to format `$dbNew` to make it look (assuming the information you have already provided)

Comment: `WHERE database_name = '$dbNew[0][0]'"` etc

Comment: Maybe you need to loop through all the arrays. Or maybe you need to implode all the DB names from the array into a comma-separated list, so you can do `WHERE database_name IN ($dbList)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each of the strings given in your output above is one of the values of `database_name` that you want to fetch, then you can do this...

```
foreach($dbNew as $row)
{
    foreach($row as $dbName)
    {
        $closing = "SELECT log_time FROM log_table WHERE database_name = '$dbName'";
        // execute this query here and do something with the results
    }
}
```